# Diameter of coins with a given height and source volume?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

We need to make $1.15\times10^5$ coins with a thickness of $2.0\times10^{-3}m(2mm)$ from a $0.12m^3$ block of silver. I'm trying to calculate what diameter the coins will end up being.

Did I set up the equation correctly where I'd get my answer from solving for D? I tried to draw it out to help understand what needs to be done. $$0.12m^3 = (1.15\times10^5) \times ((2.0\times10^{-3}m)\times \frac{\pi D}{2})$$

My solution:
$$0.12m^3 = (1.15\times10^5) \times ((2.0\times10^{-3}m)\times \pi r^2)$$
  $$\frac{0.12}{(1.15\times10^5)} = (2.0\times10^{-3})\times \pi r^2$$
  $$\pi r^2 = \frac{(0.12)}{(2.0\times10^{-3})(1.15\times10^5)}$$
  $$r^2 = \frac{(0.12)}{\pi(2.0\times10^{-3})(1.15\times10^5)}$$
  $$ 2r = 2\sqrt{\frac{(0.12)}{\pi(2.0\times10^{-3})(1.15\times10^5)}} = 0.025774m$$
  $$ D = 2.5774cm $$

Comment: One way to find the error is to check the units.  The left side has dimensions of volume ($m^3$) while the right has dimensions of $m^2$ because $D$ has dimensions of $m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term $\dfrac{\pi D}{2}$ needs to be changed to  $\dfrac{\pi D^2}{4}$.

This is because the *area* of a circle of radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$, so the area of a circle of diameter $D$ is $\dfrac{\pi D^2}{4}$.  Thus if the coin has thickness $t$, it has *volume* $\dfrac{\pi D^2}{4}t$. If we want to make $n$ coins, and the amount of silver available is $V$, then
$$V=\frac{\pi D^2}{4}tn.$$

Comment: Oh that makes sense I was wondering if I did that conversion correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you know that $\pi r^2(2*10^{-3})*1.18*10^5=0.12$

So $r^2=\frac {0.12}{2\pi10^{-3}*1.18*10^5}$ and

$\huge2r=2\sqrt {\frac{0.12}{2\pi10^{-31.18*10^5}}} \approx 0.0254443$

The problem in what you did is that $r=d/2$ so $r^2=d^2/4$ as André ponted out.